# Dependencies / Business Logic In Data Mapper (PHP - OOP)

Tags: php, oop, datamapper, business-logic

I've been writing PHP code for some time now, but have only recently stated getting to grips with the OOP approach and I'm trying to work out where certain things belong in an application.

I've written the below code which is a data mapper for handling a team's information to and from a database in my application, but I'm confused as to where / how I should apply my business logic / rules.

For example, if the delete method in the teamMapper class is called it should only proceed to running the SQL for deleting the team from the database if that team isn't involved in any matches. How would I go about doing this without violating any OOP rules or making the class hard to unit test?

I've googled this quite alot but to no avail so far, all of the data mappers that I have seen just have the SQL statement for the delete command and no logic as to if the action can actually be carried out or not.

I suppose I could inject an instance of say a MatchesMapper into my TeamMapper class through the constructor method and then proceed to run commands like $this->matchesMapper->hasMatches($team_id) or alternatively have a static method in a separate class which does the same thing, but what is the right way about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
interface TeamMapperInterface
{
    public function findById($id);
    public function insert(TeamInterface $team);
    public function update(TeamInterface $team);
    public function delete($id);
    public function isTeamByName($name);
}

class TeamMapper implements TeamMapperInterface {

private $db;

public function __construct($db)
{
    // Assign the database connection to a variable which can be used throughout the class
    $this->db = $db;
}

/**
 * Find By Id
 *
 * This function retrieves a team's information from the database and returns it as an object of "team".
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return null|Team
 */
public function findById($id)
{
    // Prepare an SQL statement for attempting to retrieve the team's information from the database
    $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `country`, `league`, `active` FROM `#` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1';

    // Execute the SQL statement
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));

    // Check to see whether the database query returned a record or not
    if(is_object($query) === false || $query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        // Return null as either the database query failed or no record could be found for the given id
        return null;
    }

    // If a team was found then attempt to load it into an a new instance of the team class
    return $this->loadTeam($query->row_array());
}

/**
 * Insert
 *
 * This function takes a team interface object and inserts it into the database.
 *
 * @param TeamInterface $team
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function insert(TeamInterface $team)
{
    // Verify that all of the variables in the object passed to this function have been set before attempting to insert the data into the database
    if(is_null($team->getName()) || is_null($team->getCountry()) || is_null($team->getLeague()) || is_null($team->getActive()))
    {
        // Throw an exception because a certain event happened
        throw new Exception('The team\'s information is incomplete and therefore cannot be added to the database.');
    }

    // Check to see if there is already a team in the database with the given name
    if($this->isTeamByName($team->getName()))
    {
        // Throw an exception because a certain event happened
        throw new Exception('The team name specified already exists in the database.');
    }

    // Prepare an SQL statement for inserting the team's information into the database
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `#` (`id`, `name`, `country`, `league`, `active`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';

    // Execute the SQL statement and then return whether it was successful or not
    return $this->db->query($sql, array('', $team->getName(), $team->getCountry(), $team->getLeague(), $team->getActive()));
}

/**
 * Update
 *
 * This function takes a team interface object and uses it to update the relevant information on the database.
 *
 * @param TeamInterface $team
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function update(TeamInterface $team)
{
    // Todo!
}

/**
 * Delete
 *
 * This function delete's a team from the database using the id specified.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function delete($id)
{
    // Determine if the variable passed to this function was an instance of team interface instead of the expected integer for the id
    if($id instanceof TeamInterface)
    {
        $id = $id->getId();
    }

    // The team can only be deleted if it doesn't have any matches assigned to it
    if(MatchesMapper::numMatchesByTeam($id) > 0)
    {
        // Throw an exception because a certain event happened
        throw new Exception('The team can only be deleted when it doesn\'t have any matches assigned to it.');
    }

    // Prepare an SQL statement for deleting the team's information from the database
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM `#` WHERE `id` = ?';

    // Execute the SQL statement and then return whether it was successful or not
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
}

/**
 * Is Team By Name
 *
 * This function queries the database to determine whether a team exists for a given name
 *
 * @param $name
 * @return bool
 */
public function isTeamByName($name)
{
    // Prepare an SQL statement for checking whether a team already exists in the database
    $sql = 'SELECT `id` FROM `#` WHERE `name` = ? LIMIT 1';

    // Execute the SQL statement
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($name));

    // Return the relevant result depending on whether a team was found or not
    return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Load Team
 *
 * This function takes an array containing some information about a given team and returns it as an object of "team"
 *
 * @param array $row
 * @return Team
 */
private function loadTeam(array $row)
{
    // Create a new object to hold the information for the team
    $team = new Team($row['name'], $row['country'], $row['league'], $row['active']);

    // Set the team's id as this can't be done through the constructor method of the team class
    $team->setId($row['id']);

    // Return the new team object
    return $team;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use InnoDB foreign key constraints to stop deletion if dependant records exist. Specifically RESTRICT.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html